# Isabelle exercise proof that trev (trev t) = t

Tags: isabelle

I'm learning Isabelle and I'm trying to solve `Exercise 3.4.3` from `A Proof Assistant for Higher-Order Logic` book (page 42).

https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/tutorial.pdf

> Define a function `trev` of type `('v, 'f) Nested.term ⇒ ('v, 'f) Nested.term` that recursively reverses the order of arguments of all
> function symbols in a term. Prove that `trev (trev t) = t`.

where

```
datatype ('v,'f)"term" = Var 'v | App 'f "('v,'f)term list"
```

My definition is

```
primrec trev :: "('v,'f)term ⇒ ('v,'f)term"
where
"trev (Var x) = Var x" |
"trev (App f ts) = App f (rev (map trev ts))"
```

I can't figure out how to prove the lemma.

##### Here's what I've tried so far.

```
lemma "trev (trev t) = (t::('v,'f)term)"
  apply(induct_tac t)
   apply(simp_all)
```

which leads to goal

```
1. ⋀x2. (⋀x2a. x2a ∈ set x2 ⟹ trev (trev x2a) = x2a) ⟹ rev (map trev (rev (map trev x2))) = x2
```

At this point I decided to backtrack and first prove a helper lemma

```
lemma map_rev_map : "map f (rev (l:: 'a list)) = rev (map f l)"
  apply(induct_tac l)
   apply(simp_all)
  done
```

once this helper lemma is proved I can proceed with the original lemma

```
apply(simp add:map_rev_map)
```

and arrive at

```
1. ⋀x2. (⋀x2a. x2a ∈ set x2 ⟹ trev (trev x2a) = x2a) ⟹ map (trev ∘ trev) x2 = x2
```

Now I want to prove a second helper lemma

```
lemma map_trev_trev : "⟦∀ t. trev (trev t) = t ⟧ ⟹ map (trev ∘ trev) ts = ts"
```

but I'm stuck here. I know I should use

```
apply(unfold o_def)
```

which leads to

```
 1. ∀t. trev (trev t) = t ⟹ map (λx. trev (trev x)) ts = ts
```

Then something like `drule spec` or `erule ssubst` and rewrite  `trev (trev x)` as `x` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does your term datatype look like? The exercise suggests it should be a mutually recursive datatype, so the `ts` in your case should be a `term_list`. But the `map` and `rev` from your definition suggest you used the normal lists from the library instead (which is actually easier and therefore better, in my opinion – but still, not what the exercise says).

Comment: And what have you tried? What (on paper) is Isabelle missing to prove the lemma with what you have tried?

Comment: @ManuelEberl mutual recursion was covered in section `3.4.1 Mutual Recursion`. This exercise come from `3.4.2 Nested Recursion` and they say to use list
 `What complicates the definition of term is the nested occurrence of term inside list on the right-hand side.`

Comment: @MathiasFleury I added my current proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for adding details to the question: you show clearly what you are trying to achieve and what is failing.

Your problem is that you are using the wrong quantifier and simp does not pick it up:

```
lemma ‹(⋀t::('a,'b) term. trev (trev (t)) = t) ⟹ map (λx. trev (trev (x::('a,'b) term))) ts = ts›
  by auto
```

I had to add the type information to make sure that `t` and `ts` get the same type.

For the sake, of giving slightly more information:

```
lemma "trev (trev t) = (t::('v,'f)term)"
  apply(induct_tac t)
   apply(simp_all)
```

produces a goal involving `rev (map trev (rev (map trev x2))) = x2`. To simplify this we need to swap rev and map. `find_thm` or the query panel, will tell you that `rev_map` looks very promising.

Now, we have to prove that `map (trev ∘ trev) x2 = x2`. The problem is that the simplifier does not rewrite `trev ∘ trev`, so you have to guide it with the so-called cong rule from map, yielding:

```
lemma "trev (trev t) = (t::('v,'f)term)"
  by (induct_tac t)
   (simp_all add: rev_map cong: map_cong)
```